# Typo3 Powermail form - Send Page UID to receiver

Tags: forms, typo3, powermail

I've created a small application form for my website. Everything works fine.

In the plugin settings there is a field called "Bodytext for Email to Receiver". This is the the mail I get, everytime somebody fills out an application form. It looks like this right now:

```
New application arrived!
{powermail_all}
```

Is it possible to get the Page UID from the application form into a variable to put it in there?

The only solutions I've found need TypoScript. Is there any other way?

Comment: why do you want to use something else, when setting the value with typoscript is easy? Or do you have a too complicated solution in mind? show your solution and explain why it is too complicated for you.

Comment: I've never used TypoScript .. and it has to be done quick. Do you have a quick solution for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with typoscript should be (according to [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForAdministrators/BestPractice/Templates/Index.html#using-typoscript-in-templates-or-rte-fields)):

use in template:

```
{f:cObject(typoscriptObjectPath:'lib.pageuid')}
```

define the typoscript:

```
lib.pageuid = TEXT
lib.pageuid.data = page:uid
```

---

I'm not sure about an additional variable for `{powermail_all}` as I'm not familiar with the extension.
If I understand the manual correctly this might be possible with :

```
plugin.tx_powermail {
    settings {
        setup {
            manipulateVariablesInPowermailAllMarker {
                // possible sections (define for each, where you need it):
                // confirmationPage, submitPage, receiverMail, senderMail, optinMail  
                submitPage {
                    pageUid = TEXT
                    pageUid.data = page:uid
                }
                senderMail {
                    pageUid = TEXT
                    pageUid.data = page:uid
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```